# how to assign values from an object member which is a list array to another object member

Tags: c#

I have two classes defined here:

```
public class datatype1
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
}
public class datatype2
{
    public List<List<double>> lat { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> lon { get; set; }
}

var data1=new datatype1();
var data2=new datatype2();
data2.lat[0][0]=30.0;
data2.lat[1][0]=40.0;
data2.lon[0][0]=30.0;
data2.lon[1][0]=40.0;
```

How to assign the values in **data2** to **data1**, accordingly, in a loop?

The original data is from the following two links:

1) ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/smcd/spb/xjin/icvs/json/npp/2016/20160103_CRIS.SDR.json

This one returns a json type like datatype1 using http://json2csharp.com/:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public int BT900 { get; set; }
    public int BT2500 { get; set; }
    public int BT1030 { get; set; }
    public int BT1500 { get; set; }
    public double iRad900 { get; set; }
    public double iRad2500 { get; set; }
    public int OverallQFlw { get; set; }
    public int OverallQFmw { get; set; }
    public int OverallQFsw { get; set; }
    public int FOV { get; set; }
    public int FOR { get; set; }
    public int Scan { get; set; }
    public int QF11 { get; set; }
    public int QF12 { get; set; }
    public int QF13 { get; set; }
    public int QF14 { get; set; }
    public int QF15 { get; set; }
    public int QF16 { get; set; }
    public int QF2lw { get; set; }
    public int QF2mw { get; set; }
    public int QF2sw { get; set; }
    public int QF32lw { get; set; }
    public int QF32mw { get; set; }
    public int QF32sw { get; set; }
    public int QF33lw { get; set; }
    public int QF33mw { get; set; }
    public int QF33sw { get; set; }
    public int QF34lw { get; set; }
    public int QF34mw { get; set; }
    public int QF34sw { get; set; }
    public int QF35lw { get; set; }
    public int QF35mw { get; set; }
    public int QF35sw { get; set; }
    public int QF41lw { get; set; }
    public int QF41mw { get; set; }
    public int QF41sw { get; set; }
    public int QF42lw { get; set; }
    public int QF42mw { get; set; }
    public int QF42sw { get; set; }
    public int QF43lw { get; set; }
    public int QF43mw { get; set; }
    public int QF43sw { get; set; }
    public int QF44lw { get; set; }
    public int QF44mw { get; set; }
    public int QF44sw { get; set; }
    public int QF45lw { get; set; }
    public int QF45mw { get; set; }
    public int QF45sw { get; set; }
    public int DSWSizeForwardLw { get; set; }
    public int DSWSizeForwardMw { get; set; }
    public int DSWSizeForwardSw { get; set; }
    public int DSWSizeReverseLw { get; set; }
    public int DSWSizeReverseMw { get; set; }
    public int DSWSizeReverseSw { get; set; }
    public int ITWSizeForwardLw { get; set; }
    public int ITWSizeForwardMw { get; set; }
    public int ITWSizeForwardSw { get; set; }
    public int ITWSizeReverseLw { get; set; }
    public int ITWSizeReverseMw { get; set; }
    public int ITWSizeReverseSw { get; set; }
    public int PRTTempsForward { get; set; }
    public int PRTTempsReverse { get; set; }
    public int ImpulseNoiselw { get; set; }
    public int ImpulseNoisemw { get; set; }
    public int ImpulseNoisesw { get; set; }
    public int ZPDFClw { get; set; }
    public int ZPDFCmw { get; set; }
    public int ZPDFCsw { get; set; }
    public int SDRFClw { get; set; }
    public int SDRFCmw { get; set; }
    public int SDRFCsw { get; set; }
    public int ZPDMglw { get; set; }
    public int ZPDMgmw { get; set; }
    public int ZPDMgsw { get; set; }
    public double DSSymmetrylw { get; set; }
    public double DSSymmetrymw { get; set; }
    public double DSSymmetrysw { get; set; }
    public double DSSpcStabForwardlw { get; set; }
    public double DSSpcStabForwardmw { get; set; }
    public double DSSpcStabForwardsw { get; set; }
    public double DSSpcStabReverselw { get; set; }
    public double DSSpcStabReversemw { get; set; }
    public double DSSpcStabReversesw { get; set; }
    public double ITSpcStabForwardlw { get; set; }
    public double ITSpcStabForwardmw { get; set; }
    public double ITSpcStabForwardsw { get; set; }
    public double ITSpcStabReverselw { get; set; }
    public double ITSpcStabReversemw { get; set; }
    public double ITSpcStabReversesw { get; set; }
    public double ITTempStabForward { get; set; }
    public double ITTempStabReverse { get; set; }
    public double ITTempCons { get; set; }
    public double MeaLaserWL { get; set; }
    public double MonLaserWL { get; set; }
    public double ResLaserWL { get; set; }
    public string Maneuver { get; set; }
    public string V { get; set; }
    public string granuleID { get; set; }
}
```

This one returns a json type like datatype2 using http://json2csharp.com/.

2) ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/smcd/spb/xjin/icvs/json/npp/2016/20160104_CRIS.SDR.json

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<double>> lat { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> lon { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> BT900 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> BT2500 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> BT1030 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> BT1500 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> iRad900 { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> iRad2500 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> OverallQFlw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> OverallQFmw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> OverallQFsw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> FOV { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> FOR { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> Scan { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF11 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF12 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF13 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF14 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF15 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF16 { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF2lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF2mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF2sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF32lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF32mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF32sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF33lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF33mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF33sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF34lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF34mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF34sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF35lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF35mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF35sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF41lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF41mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF41sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF42lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF42mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF42sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF43lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF43mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF43sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF44lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF44mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF44sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF45lw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF45mw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> QF45sw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> DSWSizeForwardLw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> DSWSizeForwardMw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> DSWSizeForwardSw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> DSWSizeReverseLw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> DSWSizeReverseMw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> DSWSizeReverseSw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ITWSizeForwardLw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ITWSizeForwardMw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ITWSizeForwardSw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ITWSizeReverseLw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ITWSizeReverseMw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ITWSizeReverseSw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> PRTTempsForward { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> PRTTempsReverse { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ImpulseNoiselw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ImpulseNoisemw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ImpulseNoisesw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ZPDFClw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ZPDFCmw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ZPDFCsw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> SDRFClw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> SDRFCmw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> SDRFCsw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ZPDMglw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ZPDMgmw { get; set; }
    public List<List<int>> ZPDMgsw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSymmetrylw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSymmetrymw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSymmetrysw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSpcStabForwardlw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSpcStabForwardmw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSpcStabForwardsw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSpcStabReverselw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSpcStabReversemw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> DSSpcStabReversesw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITSpcStabForwardlw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITSpcStabForwardmw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITSpcStabForwardsw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITSpcStabReverselw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITSpcStabReversemw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITSpcStabReversesw { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITTempStabForward { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITTempStabReverse { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ITTempCons { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> MeaLaserWL { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> MonLaserWL { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ResLaserWL { get; set; }
    public List<string> Maneuver { get; set; }
    public List<string> V { get; set; }
    public List<string> granuleID { get; set; }
}
```

In this specific case, the returned object contains 11 elements for each property.

How to assign the first element of each property in **datatype2** to **datatype1** using a **foreach** loop?

Comment: Are you trying to create new datatype1 for each lat so, lat[0][0] will be one and lat[1][0] will be a second datatype1 or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why is datatype2's lat and long members Lists of Lists instead of just simple List<double>?

Comment: I added a specific case to my question. Please check it out

Comment: Just to confirm: do you have `datatype2` as **single** or **multiple** `_CRIS.SDR.json`? That is, one `datatype2` for one `_CRIS.SDR.json` or one `datatype2` for **all** your `_CRIS.SDR.json`?

Answer (score 0):

```
datatype2 data2 = GetYourJsonData();
for(var i=0; i<data2.lat.Count; i++)
{
    datatype1 data1 = new datatype1 
        {
            lat = data2.lat[i][0],
            lon = data.lon[i][0] // remember check for nulls
        };

       // do your stuff with data1
}
```

Comment: this is also the method that t I am currently using. It results in a very long list of code when assigning the property value one after another. there are actually 100 properties in this case. I am looking for a method to do it in a foreach loop. I am stuck because the properties in datatype2 are all list<list>. Dealing list arrays inside a class object is not very straightforward. I am trying to look for a solution from here

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Your question is not clear. What do you expect to avoid with foreach?? You have two different types how do you expect avoiding the assignment of each property?? Only way would be reflection or some mapping tool (which actually use reflection).

Comment: Yes, we are getting close when talking about reflection. The reason why I want to avoid writing assignment lines one by one is because the properties in these two class share the same name. I guess there might be a smarter way to work it out. But I am new to C# and I am not very familiar with how to use mapping tools in my case.